# Apply multiple tuples at the same time in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++20, type-traits

I have `N` tuples `Foo, Bar, ..., Baz` with 'M' arbitrary element types. I can run `std::apply` on each tuple, and invoke some arbitrary operation on its elements:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

auto operation(auto& foo, auto& bar)
{

//operation can be arbitrary

    return foo + bar;
}


int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, float, double> Foo{1, 2.0f, 3.0};
    std::tuple<float, bool, char> Bar{1.0f, true, 'a'};

    auto result = std::apply(
        [&](auto &&...foo) {
            return std::apply([&](auto &&...bar) { 

return std::make_tuple(operation(foo, bar)...); }, Bar);
        },
        Foo);



    return 0;
}
```

These expressions become verbose and ugly when the number of tuples increase. How would I proceed to design a `multi_apply`:

```
    auto result = multi_apply([&](auto&& ... foo, auto&& ... bar, ..., auto&& ... baz)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(operation(foo, bar, ..., baz)...);
    }, Foo, Bar, ..., Baz);
```

Here is a "2D-variadic" example, demonstrating what `multi_apply` should handle.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

auto operation(auto &...foo_bar_baz_elem)
{

    //operation can be arbitrary

    return (foo_bar_baz_elem + ...);
}


int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, float, double> Foo{1, 2.0f, 3.0};
    std::tuple<float, bool, char> Bar{1.0f, true, 'a'};

    //...

    std::tuple<char, float, char> Baz{1.0f, true, 'a'};

    auto result = std::apply(
        [&](auto &&...foo) {
            return std::apply(
                [&](auto &&...bar) {
                    // apply ...
                    //...
                    return std::apply([&](auto &&...baz) { return std::make_tuple(operation(foo, bar, ..., baz)...); },
                                      Bar);
                },
                Baz);
        },
        Foo);


    return 0;
}
```

Note: Input argument size of `operation()` is known at the time of `Foo, Bar,..., Baz` declaration, but `multi_apply` needs to be able to handle all sizes.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking to generate the cartesian product of the tuples, not just zip them together?

Comment: It is a 'NxM' "2D-tuple" where all N columns are passed as input arguments to an arbirary operation, in order to return 'N' return values from the operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lets you pass around compile time natural numbers as values:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
```

And this is a tuple of them:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
using indexes_t = std::tuple< index_t<Is>... >;
```

Next, extract the indexes of a tuple:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr indexes_t<Is...> to_indexes( std::index_sequence<Is...> )
{ return {}; }

template<class...Ts>
constexpr auto to_indexes( std::tuple<Ts...> const& ) {
  return to_indexes( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{} );
}
```

Also, a nice primitive "map" - this applies f to each element of a tuple and makes a tuple from the result.

```
template<class Tuple, class F>
constexpr auto map_tuple( Tuple&& tuple, F f ) {
  return std::apply(
    [&](auto&&...ts){
      return std::make_tuple( f(ts)... );
    },
    std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)
  );
}
```

we can now define `shuffle_tuples`. The empty shuffle is empty:

```
constexpr std::tuple<> shuffle_tuples() { return {}; }
```

For non-empty shuffles, we take the number of elements in the first tuple and then pick those in turn for each of the tuples:

```
template<class T0, class...Tuples>
constexpr auto shuffle_tuples( T0&& t0, Tuples&&... tuples ) {
  return map_tuple(
    to_indexes(t0),
    [&](auto I) {
      return std::make_tuple(
        std::get<I>(std::forward<T0>(t0),
        std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...
      );
    }
  );
}
```

and that should do it.

Comment: The tuple-shuffle (or zip operation) solved the issue! Full `Foo, Bar, Baz`-example: https://godbolt.org/z/xrdYfn8Wb

Comment: Note: The comments ordering of `std::apply` arguments in `map_tuple` needs to be flipped.

Comment: @Anon232 Fixed ordering of tuple arguments.  Sorry, I answer questions off-hand and fix compile typos later, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 2):

For `[](auto&&... foo, auto&& ... bar, ..., auto&& ... baz)`,
deduction only happens for last pack (and only first one can be provided). So that signature is not possible.

`std::index_sequence` might be an option:

```
[&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    return std::make_tuple(operation(std::get<Is>(foo),
                                     std::get<Is>(bar),
                                     // ...,
                                     std::get<Is>(baz))...);
  }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<decltype(Foo)>>())
```

Comment: I tried going this way with the integer sequences, but i can't manually write foo, bar, ..., baz. The problem is in a sense a 2D-variadic tuple, which needs to be expanded across columns (foo,bar,baz) and rows ('M' elements).

Comment: @Anon232 The `std::get<Is>(foo), std::get<Is>(bar), ..., std::get<Is>(baz)` can be from a pack: `return std::apply([&]<typename... Tpl>(Tpl&&... tuples) { return std::make_tuple(operation(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tpl>(tuple))...)) }, my_tuple_of_tuples)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the operation you're looking for is a left-fold, except that each element is a tuple of different types, and `std::apply` is involved in combining them.
We can start by creating a `pack_left_fold` operation that works with parameters packs in general:

```cpp
template <typename BinaryOp, typename Head1, typename Head2, typename ...Tail>
auto pack_left_fold(BinaryOp op, Head1 &&head1, Head2 &&head2, Tail &&...tail)
{
    // recursion base case: combine two elements
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Tail) == 0) {
        // use std::move to potentially use rvalue overloads of call operator
        return std::move(op)(head1, head2);
    }
    // left-fold: combine two elements and combine with rest
    else {
        // rely on temporary materialization to save one move constructor call
        auto &&result = op(head1, head2);
        return pack_left_fold(std::move(op),
                              std::forward<decltype(result)>(result),
                              std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
    }
}
```

Once that is out of the way, we implement a `tuple_pack_left_fold` operation which uses `std::apply` in its binary operation:

```cpp
// Accept const& in parameters because each tuple member is being accessed multiple times,
// so we cannot safely move anyways.
template <typename BinaryOp, typename Head1, typename Head2, typename ...Tail>
auto tuple_pack_left_fold(BinaryOp op,
                          const Head1 &head1,
                          const Head2 &head2,
                          const Tail &...tail)
{
    // delegate to pack_left_fold
    return pack_left_fold([op](const auto &t1, const auto &t2)
    {
        return std::apply([&](const auto&...args1) {
            return std::apply([&](const auto &...args2) {
                return std::make_tuple(op(args1, args2)...);
            }, t2);
        }, t1);
    }, head1, head2, tail...);
}
```

Now we can combine tuples with `std::apply` like you did in your original code with arbitrarily many tuples:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, float, double> Foo{1, 2.0f, 3.0};
    std::tuple<float, bool, char> Bar{1.0f, true, 'a'};

    auto op = [](auto l, auto r) { return operation(l, r); };
    tuple_pack_left_fold(op, Foo, Bar, Foo, Foo, Bar, Bar);
}
```

Comment: Link to full working example of @Jan Schultke 's example: https://godbolt.org/z/drbfsa9f7

Comment: I'm looking for a left-fold operation with respect to the 'M' elements in each of 'Foo, Bar, ..., Baz', but I'm also looking to fold over the 'N' number of tuples 'Foo, Bar, ..., Baz'.

Comment: Can you present some expected output for two and more dimensions? I'm confused what exactly you want the result of such an operation to be.

Comment: For the `Foo, Bar` example the result should be: `std::tuple<float, float, double>`, where elements are added: `int + float`, `float + bool`, `double + char`. I provided an additional, 2D-variadic example.